# r stat_density2d polygon NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R 3.2.4, ggplot2 2.1.0 and am running into an error when using stat_density_2d with ggplot(). I can reproduce the error using an example from the ggplot website.

```
library('ggplot2')
m <- ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) + geom_point() +
 xlim(0.5, 6) + ylim(40, 110)
m + stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

I get a plot of points only, no density contours, and the following warning:
Warning message:
In validDetails.polygon(x) : NAs introduced by coercion. The dataset does not have any missing values.  I can run the other example without error.

```
m + geom_density_2d()
```

I've looked at the ggplot GitHub site and didn't see any known issues that looked relevant (only some old ones from ~2013 that were already resolved). Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running R 3.2.4 and ggplot2 2.1.0 and the above code renders the contours fine. Anything relevant from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: `geom = "density_2d"` works, but `geom = "polygon"` does not. I have tried several working examples. Do they both use kde2d()? I have MASS version 7.3-45.

Comment: `R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices utils     datasets  stats     graphics  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Hmisc_3.17-2    ggplot2_2.1.0   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-3 lattice_0.20-33 foreign_0.8-66 
[7] car_2.1-2 `

Answer (score 5):

I think I found something.

If you put `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` in your script, you'll have the problem.

I simply removed it as a workaround and it works.

Comment: I added a line `options(stringsAsFactors=T)` and then it would plot the contours. Apparently somewhere that option was changed for me. Thanks!